# Using Dagger2 in AOSP

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-source

I am trying to bundle my app as a system app in my AOSP build, but I am getting errors on the classes that Dagger is generating.

I've tried https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/190 and the links in that post, but none are working as they say.

```
error: cannot find symbol
component = DaggerDemoApplication_ApplicationComponent.builder()
            ^
symbol:   variable DaggerDemoApplication_ApplicationComponent
```

Any help/advice?

Comment: `errors on the classes that Dagger is generating` which errors?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko updated the question.

Comment: How did you add the dependency to the project?